# Delete table rows in loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

We are using SQL Server 2000. We have a heavy database with over 100000 images. Currently I'm deleting records with this query:

```
DELETE FROM T_JBSHEETDATA
WHERE (F_JBREF NOT IN (SELECT JOB_REF_NUMBER
                       FROM  T_JBDTLS))
```

but unfortunately it only deletes 500 records at a time. If I take more records the server dies (server timeout). How do I create a loop of x rows until it's finished?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What indexes are defined? What are the FK and PK of each table?

Comment: That's a rather small number of records. What do you mean by server timeout? There are connection timouts and command timeouts. You probably experience the second. How long does the query run before it times out? Have you defined any indexes on JOB_REF_NUMBER and F_JBREF? Are other queries using the same tables, locking the records and preventing deletes? Running a bad query in a loop will only make it take longer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way to do "top N deletes".

A few ideas.  You can configure the @TopSize until you find the good "goldie locks" value.  Not too big, not too small.

You could also remove the while loop, and then track the @RowCount (after the delete statement)......and if you had client code....return the delete-count, and keep calling the (stored procedure?) over and over until the delete count was zero.

NOW, I would see if an index could improve performance before resorting to the below.
But I'm trying to answer your question..............as asked.

```
/* START TSQL */

if exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 'Television')
      BEGIN
            DROP TABLE [dbo].[Television]
      END
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Television] (
      TelevisionUUID [uniqueidentifier] not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() ,
      TelevisionName varchar(64) not null ,
      TelevisionKey int not null ,
      IsCheckedOut bit default 0
)    
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Television_TelevisionUUID
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TelevisionUUID)
GO


ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Television_TelevisionName_UNIQUE
UNIQUE (TelevisionName)
GO


set nocount on

declare @counter int
select @counter = 11000
declare @currentTVName varchar(24)
declare @TopSize int
select @TopSize = 10

while @counter > 10000  /* this loop counter is ONLY here for fake data,….do not use this syntax for production code */
begin

      select @currentTVName = 'TV:     '+ convert(varchar(24) , @counter)

      INSERT into dbo.Television ( TelevisionName , TelevisionKey ) values ( @currentTVName , @counter)

      select @counter = @counter - 1     
end


/* Everything above is just setup data, the crux of the code is below this line */


select count(*) as TV_Total_COUNT_Pre from dbo.Television

declare @DeleteLoopCounter int 
select @DeleteLoopCounter = 0

while exists ( select top 1 * from dbo.Television )

 BEGIN
        select @DeleteLoopCounter = @DeleteLoopCounter + 1

        ;
        WITH cte1 AS      
         (  SELECT
              TOP (@TopSize)

           TelevisionUUID ,  /* <<Note, the columns here must be available to the output */
           IsCheckedOut       
              FROM  
                    dbo.Television tv     
            WITH ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK )  /* <<Optional Hints, but helps with concurrency issues  */

              /* WHERE conditions can be put there as well */

              ORDER BY /* order by is optional, and I would probably remove it for a delete operation */
                    tv.TelevisionKey DESC       
        )
                                      /* UPDATE cte1 SET  IsCheckedOut = 1 */ /* this code has nothing to do with the delete solution, but shows how you could use this same trick for an "update top N" */

        Delete deleteAlias
        from dbo.Television deleteAlias
        where exists ( select null from cte1 innerAlias where innerAlias.TelevisionUUID = deleteAlias.TelevisionUUID )
        ;

        print '/@DeleteLoopCounter/'
        print @DeleteLoopCounter
        print ''

        select count(*) as TV_Total_COUNT_Post from dbo.Television

    END
```

EDIT

Sql Server 2000 specific info:

NOTE.  Since you have 2000, you will have to HARD CODE the @TopSize value.  But I will leave the code "as is" for future readers.  Again, you'll have to remove @TopSize and then use a value like "1000" or similar.  Remove the () around the @TopSize near the select.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to improve the performance of your query instead of trying to figure out how to delete in a loop.

**1.** Make sure there is an index on table `T_JBDTLS.JOB_REF_NUMBER`. If it's missing that might be the cause of the slowdown.

**2.** Change your query to use a join instead of a sub-select. Something like:

```
  DELETE FROM T_JBSHEETDATA
    FROM T_JBSHEETDATA D
        LEFT JOIN T_JBDTLS J ON D.F_JBREF = J.JOB_REF_NUMBER
    WHERE J.JOB_REF_NUMBER IS NULL
```

**3.** Are there any triggers on the table that you're deleting from? What about cascade deletes? Triggers on the table that is being cascade-deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try a "not exists" clause instead of a "not in".

I believe the below is the correct translation.

```
Delete deleteAlias
/* select deleteAlias.* */
from dbo.T_JBSHEETDATA deleteAlias
where not exists ( select null from dbo.[T_JBDTLS] innerDets where innerDets.JOB_REF_NUMBER = deleteAlias.F_JBREF )
```

Here is a generic Northwind version that will delete any Order(s) that do(es) not have any (child) Order-Details.

```
Use Northwind
GO


Delete deleteAlias
/* select deleteAlias.* */
from dbo.Orders deleteAlias
where not exists ( select null from dbo.[Order Details] innerDets where innerDets.OrderId = deleteAlias.OrderId )
```